# neo4j cannot start on Mac m1: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, macos, neo4j, apple-m1

I've tried neo4j with version 4.2.3 and 4.2.4 with openjdk11 and openjdk16, none of them works.

Here is the full log of this error:

INFO Starting...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/tenetwang/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna7021027558011019290.tmp: dlopen(/Users/tenetwang/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna7021027558011019290.tmp, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/tenetwang/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna7021027558011019290.tmp: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
/Users/tenetwang/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna7021027558011019290.tmp: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2627)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1018)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:988)
at com.sun.jna.Native.(Native.java:195)
at org.neo4j.internal.unsafe.UnsafeUtil.allocateMemory(UnsafeUtil.java:441)
at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.VictimPageReference.getVictimPage(VictimPageReference.java:42)
at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.(MuninnPageCache.java:284)
at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.(MuninnPageCache.java:256)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.createPageCache(ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.java:99)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.getOrCreatePageCache(ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.java:87)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.module.GlobalModule.createPageCache(GlobalModule.java:373)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.module.GlobalModule.lambda$new$1(GlobalModule.java:219)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.module.GlobalModule.tryResolveOrCreate(GlobalModule.java:261)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.module.GlobalModule.(GlobalModule.java:218)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.createGlobalModule(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:252)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:126)
at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.createNeo(CommunityBootstrapper.java:36)
at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:134)
at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:90)
at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:35)

Answer (score 0):

I run Neo4j on M1 via Docker and I know when I was looking into that that the JNA dependency needed to be updated (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12676). Given the first line of the exception it would point at that.